# JavaScript: Find all parents for element in tree recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have a tree somthing like this

```
var datas = {
    'tree': [
        {
            'name': 'name1',
            'tree': [
                {'name': 'name2'},
                {'name': 'name3'},
                {
                    'name': 'name4',
                    'tree': [
                        {'name': 'name5'},
                        {'name': 'name6'}
                    ]
                },
                {'name': 'name7'}
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'name8',
            'tree': [
                {'name': 'name9'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the parents of the specifig id

for example in the tree demo, if I look for 'name5' I want to find "name1,name4,name5"

I wrote this code but the results wrong and I got the ids of other elements and not the parents only

This is my code

```
 keys: string[];
  pathFound: boolean = false;
 getLevel(event: iEventBase, id: string, path: string[]): void {
    if (this.pathFound) return;
    event.content.forEach((key) => {
      if (key.id == id) {
        if(!path){
          path =  [];;
        }
        path.push(key.id);
        this.keys = path;
        this.pathFound = true;
        return;
      }
      if (key.type === "page") {
        if(!path){
          path = [];
        }
        path.push(key.id);
        this.getLevel(key, id, path);
      }
    })
  }
}
this.getLevel(state.mainEvent.content.page, event.id, null);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach by checking the name and return a new data structure with only the nodes to the wanted object.

```js
function find({ tree = [], ...object }, name) {
    var result;
    if (object.name === name) return object;
    return tree.some(o => result = find(o, name)) && Object.assign({}, object, { tree: [result] });
}

var datas = { tree: [{ name: 'name1', tree: [{ name: 'name2' }, { name: 'name3' }, { name: 'name4', tree: [{ name: 'name5' }, { name: 'name6' }] }, { name: 'name7' }] }, { name: 'name8', tree: [{ name: 'name9' }] }] };

console.log(find(datas, 'name5'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works, but this is not returning the same object reference. I mean in my case I have applied this method and push the values in immediate parent of a node, but this does not reflect in the actual tree??

Comment: This (**With parent elements**) looks the same, can you please what changes, you have made :) ?

Comment: maybe i don't understand your goal, please add an example of the wanted result.

Comment: Actually i want to delete a node from the tree, so i find the immediate parent node and filter the data of its child, by using this code block, which works perfectly fine to locate the all parents objects. But the references it returns are not the same from the tree nodes, so even if I filter the child record of immediate parent node, it does not reflect in the tree node!!

Comment: do you want to mutate the data? or a new tree upt to the wanted node?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199224/discussion-between-sunil-garg-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could take a recursive approach to this problem. The basic idea here is to look down through the tree for a node whose name matches the node name that your looking to find parents for (ie `name5`).

Once such a node has been found, then return an array, appending the corresponding parent name of the node to the array until the recursion completely unwinds.

So, something along the lines of this should work:

```js
var datas = {
    'tree': [
        {
            'name': 'name1',
            'tree': [
                {'name': 'name2'},
                {'name': 'name3'},
                {
                    'name': 'name4',
                    'tree': [
                        {'name': 'name5'},
                        {'name': 'name6'}
                    ]
                },
                {'name': 'name7'}
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'name8',
            'tree': [
                {'name': 'name9'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

function findParents(node, searchForName) {

  // If current node name matches the search name, return
  // empty array which is the beginning of our parent result
  if(node.name === searchForName) {
    return []
  }
  
  // Otherwise, if this node has a tree field/value, recursively
  // process the nodes in this tree array
  if(Array.isArray(node.tree)) {
  
    for(var treeNode of node.tree) {

      // Recursively process treeNode. If an array result is
      // returned, then add the treeNode.name to that result
      // and return recursively
      const childResult = findParents(treeNode, searchForName)

      if(Array.isArray(childResult)) {
        return [ treeNode.name ].concat( childResult );
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log( findParents(datas, 'name5') )
```