# Find path in tree by direct path

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have similiary problem like here: [JavaScript: Find all parents for element in tree recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277219/javascript-find-all-parents-for-element-in-tree-recursive)

But I don't find path by `name` but by `direct path`.

```
const path = ["name1", "name4", "name5"];

const data = [
    {
        'name': 'name1',
        'tree': [
            {'name': 'name2'},
            {'name': 'name3'},
            {
                'name': 'name4',
                'tree': [
                    {'name': 'name5'},
                    {'name': 'name6'}
                ]
            },
            {'name': 'name7'}
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'name8',
        'tree': [
            {'name': 'name9'}
        ]
    }
];
```

It returns every possible path or nothing.

When `path` is too short, it returns nothing.

When `path` is too long, it returns nothing.

Thanks for help!

Examples of desired output:

```
const path = ["name1", "name4", "name5"];
findAPath(data, path)
```

Returns: `["name1", "name4", "name5"]`

```
const path = ["name1", "name7", "name5"];
findAPath(data, path)
```

Returns `[]`

```
const path = ["name1", "name4", "name5", "name5"];
findAPath(data, path)
```

Returns `[]`

My trying:

```
let index = 0;
function find(data, index) {
    let index = index;
    data.some((o) => {
        if(o.name == path[index]) {
            index++;
            find(o.tree, index);
        }
    });
    // I don't know what return here.
    // I need to probably return path where I am.
    return <>;
}
```

Comment: can you give an example? `path = ["name1", "name4", "name5"]` should return what? Also, and most important, have you tried something?

Comment: Edited. I tried some recursive functions, but without success. It blow my mind any way I tried.

Comment: ok, with success or not, it is expected on StackOverflow that you show your attempts, so people can debug and help on how to achieve the desired result, otherwise it will look like you want us to code it for you

Comment: Edited. Sorry. My trying was not something big, it didn't seem important to me.

Answer (score 3):

**using `Array.prototype.flatMap`**

Here's a functional solution using a [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) technique -

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath = (tree = [], names = [], r = []) =>
  tree.length && names.length                              // base: and
    ? tree.flatMap(branch => findPath1(branch, names, r))
    : tree.length || names.length                          // inductive: xor
        ? []
        : [ r ]                                            // inductive: nor                                     // inductive: nor

const findPath1 = ({ name = "", tree = [] } = {}, [ q = None, ...more ] = [], r = []) =>
  name === "" && q === None                    // base: and
    ? [ r ]
    : name === "" || q === None || name !== q  // inductive: xor
        ? []
        : findPath(tree, more, [ ...r, q ])    // inductive: nor

findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"])
// => [ [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ] ]
```

NB if your data contains *multiple* paths to the input values, *all* paths will be returned -

```
const data = [
  {
      'name': 'name1',                   // name1
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name2'},
          {'name': 'name3'},
          {
              'name': 'name4',           // name1->name4
              'tree': [
                  {'name': 'name5'},     // name1->name4->name5
                  {'name': 'name6'}
              ]
          },
          {
            'name': 'name4',             // name1->name4
            'tree': [
                {'name': 'name5'},       // name1->name4->name5
                {'name': 'name6'}
              ]
          },
          {'name': 'name7'}
      ]
  },
  {
      'name': 'name8',
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name9'}
      ]
  }
]
```

Just like you asked, it returns every possible path, or nothing -

```
findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"])
// => [ [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ],
//      [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ] ]

findPath(data, [ "name1", "name7" ])
// => [ [ "name1", "name7" ] ]

findPath(data, [ "name1", "name9" ])
// => []
```

When a path is too short or too long, it will return nothing -

```
findPath(data, [ "name1", "name4" ])
// => []

findPath(data, [ "name1", "name4", "name5", "name6" ])
// => []
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath = (tree = [], names = [], r = []) =>
  tree.length && names.length
    ? tree.flatMap(branch => findPath1(branch, names, r))
    : tree.length || names.length
        ? []
        : [ r ]

const findPath1 = ({ name = "", tree = [] } = {}, [ q = None, ...more ] = [], r = []) =>
  name === "" && q === None
    ? [ r ]
    : name === "" || q === None || name !== q
        ? []
        : findPath(tree, more, [ ...r, q ])

const data = [
  {
      'name': 'name1',
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name2'},
          {'name': 'name3'},
          {
              'name': 'name4',
              'tree': [
                  {'name': 'name5'},
                  {'name': 'name6'}
              ]
          },
          {'name': 'name7'}
      ]
  },
  {
      'name': 'name8',
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name9'}
      ]
  }
]

console.log(findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"]))
// [ [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ] ]

console.log(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name7" ]))
// [ [ "name1", "name7" ] ]

console.log(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name9" ]))
// []
```

---

**using Generators**

Here's an alternative implementation using generators -

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath = function* (tree = [], names = [], r = [])
{ if (tree.length && names.length)        // base: and
    for (const branch of tree)
      yield* findPath1(branch, names, r)
  else if (tree.length || names.length)   // inductive: xor
    return
  else                                    // inductive: nor
    yield r
}

const findPath1 = function* ({ name = "", tree = [] } = {}, [ q = None, ...more ] = [], r = [])
{ if (name === "" && q === None)                     // base: and
    yield r
  else if (name === "" || q === None || name !== q)  // inductive: xor
    return
  else                                               // inductive: nor
    yield* findPath(tree, more, [ ...r, q ])
}
```

It has the exact same output as above, only to coerce the iterable generator into an array, we use `Array.from` -

```
Array.from(findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"]))
// => [ [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ] ]

Array.from(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name7" ]))
// => [ [ "name1", "name7" ] ]

Array.from(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name9" ]))
// => []
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath = function* (tree = [], names = [], r = [])
{ if (tree.length && names.length)
    for (const branch of tree)
      yield* findPath1(branch, names, r)
  else if (tree.length || names.length)
    return
  else
    yield r
}

const findPath1 = function* ({ name = "", tree = [] } = {}, [ q = None, ...more ] = [], r = [])
{ if (name === "" && q === None)
    yield r
  else if (name === "" || q === None || name !== q)
    return
  else
    yield* findPath(tree, more, [ ...r, q ])
}

const data = [
  {
      'name': 'name1',
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name2'},
          {'name': 'name3'},
          {
              'name': 'name4',
              'tree': [
                  {'name': 'name5'},
                  {'name': 'name6'}
              ]
          },
          {'name': 'name7'}
      ]
  },
  {
      'name': 'name8',
      'tree': [
          {'name': 'name9'}
      ]
  }
]

console.log(Array.from(findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"])))
// [ [ "name1", "name4", "name5" ] ]

console.log(Array.from(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name7" ])))
// [ [ "name1", "name7" ] ]

console.log(Array.from(findPath(data, [ "name1", "name9" ])))
// []
```

---

**how they're the same; how they're not**

Note the similarity between the two implementations and how the result is formed. Both use mutual recursion. The functional solution uses expressions whereas the generator solution uses statements. The generator implementation extends a distinct advantage where by we can chose to stop or continue iteration ("finding") whenever we want.

For example, imagine an input where there are ten (10) unique paths for the given input. Perhaps we want to just return the first match,

```
const findFirst = (tree = [], names = []) =>
{ for (const path of findPath(tree, names))
    return path
}
```

Or get the first three (3) matches -

```
const findFirst3 = (tree = [], names = []) =>
{ const r = []
  for (const path of findPath(tree, names))
    if (r.length < 3)
      r.push(path)
  return r
}
```

Or get the first `N` -

```
const findFirstN = (tree = [], names = [], n = 0) =>
{ const r = []
  for (const path of findPath(tree, names))
    if (r.length < n)
      r.push(path)
  return r
}
```

Generators are flexible like this. By contrast, the `flatMap` implementation is eager and *always* returns *all* results.