# Find path in tree by direct path with types

Tags: javascript

I try to improve this code: [Find path in tree by direct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680671/find-path-in-tree-by-direct-path)

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const findPath = (tree = [], names = [], r = []) =>
  tree.length && names.length
    ? tree.flatMap(branch => findPath1(branch, names, r))
    : tree.length || names.length
        ? []
        : [ r ]

const findPath1 = ({ name = "", tree = [] } = {}, [ q = None, ...more ] = [], r = []) =>
  name === "" && q === None
    ? [ r ]
    : name === "" || q === None || name !== q
        ? []
        : findPath(tree, more, [ ...r, q ])

findPath(data, ["name1", "name4", "name5"])
```

I'll have this `data`:

```
const data = [
    {
        'name': 'name1',
        'tree': [
            {'name': 'name2'},
            {'type': 'type1'},
            {
                'name': 'name4',
                'tree': [
                    {'name': 'name5'},
                    {'type': 'type2'}
                ]
            },
            {'name': 'name7'}
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'name8',
        'tree': [
            {'type': 'number'}
        ]
    }
];

const types = [
    {
        'type': 'number',
        'tree': [
            {
                'name': 'number1',
                'tree': [
                    {
                      'type': 'number'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'number2',
                'tree': [
                    {
                      'type': 'number'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'type': 'type1',
        'error': true,
        'tree': [
            {
                'name': 'name1',
                'tree': [
                    {
                      'type': 'type2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]        
    },
    {
        'type': 'type2',
        'tree': [
            {
                'name': 'name3',
                'end': true,
                'tree': [
                    {
                       'type': 'type3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'type': 'type3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'type': 'type3',
        'end': true,
        'tree': [
            {
                'name': 'name4'
            },
            {
                'name': 'name6'
            }
         ]
    },
];
```

Expected output:

```
findPath(data, ["name1", "name1"]); // ["name1", "name1"]
findPath(data, ["name1", "name1", "name3"]); // []
findPath(data, ["name1", "name1", "name3", "name4"]); // ["name1", "name1", "name3", "name4"]
findPath(data, ["name8", "number1", "number1", "number2"]); // ["name8", "number1", "number1", "number2"]
```

Types can have no limit like number.

But if there is `end: true` it has to have continue, so `name` or `type`.

None of my trying does not work.

I have a few question about the function from another topic.

1) What does `r` is what does it mean?

2) What does `cost None = Symbol();` is what does it mean?

3) What does `q` is what does it mean?

4) What does `...more` is what does it mean?

Thank you for ur help or any hint!

Comment: Don't look at code like that and expect to be able to understand it. It's written in far too "clever" of a way to be easily interpretted. The code is using some very unique ways to solve the problem. Find another code sample that solves the same problem and start there. If you come across another one that is easier to understand I'm sure we would be more than happy to help.

Comment: @Andrew I doubt there is another code to do the same thing. I found only this. It is also too hard to read for you?